# How can I change font color and specification of additional informations of installation directory chooser

Tags: java, install4j

How can I change the disk space information font color and specification of installation directory chooser?

[Installation directory chooser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iViQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the "Initialization script" property of the "Installation directory chooser" form component to

```
JComponent container = formEnvironment.getComponentTuple(component).getCenterComponent();
for (int i = 0; i < container.getComponentCount(); i++) {
    JComponent c = (JComponent)container.getComponent(i);
    if (c instanceof JLabel) {
        c.setFont(c.getFont().deriveFont(java.awt.Font.BOLD));
    }
}
```

both labels will be shown in bold font.